# Count Distinct vs Group By Discrepancy

Tags: mysql

I have a large table of 160 million rows.  I am trying to get an accurate count of the unique phone numbers.  I am getting the following results:

```
select count(distinct `number`) from customers;
```

Results = about 143 million rows

```
select `number` from customers group by `number`;
```

Results = about 4.3 million rows

When I have run similar count(distinct) and group by queries on other smaller tables in the past, I have received the same number of results between the two.

Any thoughts as to what is causing the discrepancy here?

Update:

I used awk to grab the number column out of the csv.  I then ran these two commands in Linux:

```
sort temp | uniq > temp_unique

wc -l temp_unique
```

The results (about 4.3 million) were the same as the second select statement above.

I removed the index and rebuilt it and now the first count statement above returns the 4.3 million rows, so it does appear I had a corrupt index.  I am curious why a corrupt index would show more results in the count versus less.  Any thoughts on that?  (I am using innodb btw.)

Comment: The second query returns a result set - perhaps you have run out of memory

Comment: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp1 AS SELECT number FROM customers;`  Then run these same two queries against the table tmp1. Same results? Different? If the original table is MyISAM, and particularly if the same data in a different table results in the expected matching counts, then I suspect subtle index corruption.

Comment: I updated my post above.  Thanks for the suggestions.